# Change box size when resize window with css

Tags: html, css

I have this simple website

```
<div style=" position: relative; margin-right: 40px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px; position: relative;">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 200px; position: relative; margin-right: 40px;">Right Stuff</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

and I want that the middle stuff-box-width grow up when I resize the window so that between the middle stuff-box and the right stuff-box is no empty content.

[image: Here can you see what I want]

How can I get this "effect"?

Comment: give width in percentage instead of fixed width. float both left.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/8ws2H/

Comment: try it. http://jsfiddle.net/zrVPJ/8/  min css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="position: relative; margin-right: 40px; width: 100%;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 60%; position: relative; border: 1px solid #000;">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; position: relative; margin-right: 40px;margin-left: 10px; border: 1px solid #000;">Right Stuff</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Try this you will get a fix size for second box as 200px while 60% for first box.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you can achieve this with percentage widths.  Be carful though, if you leave your margins at fixed widths then the layout can break.

```
<div style=" position: relative; margin-right: 40px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 58%; position: relative; margin-right:2%;" class="middle-div">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 38%; position: relative; margin-right: 2%;" class="right-div">Right Stuff</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8WqX/)

Also, you should really try to avoid using inline styles like this.  Instead, I'd recommend something along the lines of:

```
/* CSS in style.css */
.parent-div {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 40%;
}
.middle-div, .right-div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.middle-div {
    width: 58%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.right-div {
    width: 38%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Then your markup can be reduced to:

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="middle-div">Middle DIV</div>
    <div class="right-div">Right DIV</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your image you need left column fluid and right one fixed: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ws2H/)**

```
<div id="outerdiv">
        <div id="right">Right Stuff</div>
        <div id="left">Middle Stuff</div>
    </div>

#outerdiv {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use responsive grid system like [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

[demo](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)